# To get the text of the selected item in the dropdown list in java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to get the text of the selected item in the drop down list. I tried the following code

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlTime.ClientID");  
var selectedTime = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

but it gives me "Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is null or undefined"

can any one please help me out with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
var e = document.getElementById("<%= ddlTime.ClientID%>");
```

Not:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlTime.ClientID");
```

My little sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHxdS/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify `<%= %>`

```
var e = document.getElementById("<%= ddlTime.ClientID%>");
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
    function WeekChange() {
        var Week = window.document.getElementById("ddWeek").value;
        if (Week != "--Select--") {
            window.document.getElementById("txtDetect").value = "Every " + Week;
        }
        else {
            window.document.getElementById("txtDetect").value = " ";
        }
    }

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddWeek" runat="server" onchange="javascript:WeekChange();">
```